# Null pointer exception when edit my custom contact in Gxlaxy 2 (4.0.3)

Tags: android, contacts, galaxy

In my application i add contacts to contacts list by ContentProviderOperation.

In Galaxy 3 and 4 it's worked perfect.
In Galaxy 2 i crash when i try to edit contact from the contacts list itself.

I google and read that this issue happen to some android developers in this case, but i don't find solution to this exception.

This my exception:

```
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at com.android.contacts.editor.ContactEditorFragment.bindEditors(ContactEditorFragment.java)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at com.android.contacts.editor.ContactEditorFragment.bindEditorsForExistingContact(ContactEditorFragment.java)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at com.android.contacts.editor.ContactEditorFragment.setData(ContactEditorFragment.java)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at com.android.contacts.editor.ContactEditorFragment$6.onLoadFinished(ContactEditorFragment.java)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at com.android.contacts.editor.ContactEditorFragment$6.onLoadFinished(ContactEditorFragment.java)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:438)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:406)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:125)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at com.android.contacts.ContactLoader$LoadContactTask.onPostExecute(ContactLoader.java)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at com.android.contacts.ContactLoader$LoadContactTask.onPostExecute(ContactLoader.java)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
12-19 10:26:51.685: E/AndroidRuntime(6439):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I know what is null pointer exception.. i don't understand why it's happen on specific device.

Comment: You dont understood. i develop for some years. this exception occurs in internal android classes. I read in google that this exception occurs to android developers in case that you add custom contact to device and try edit.

Comment: You know, I looked at that stack trace twice and still missed that. My apologies.